# Expression tree to SQL with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We have a column where JSON data is stored as a string. This JSON data is read and converted through materialization to an `IDictionary<string, object>`. This all works fine until I want to filter on it. The filtering is only applied after getting the data from the database. We will have millions of records so this is not acceptable. My filter is being completely ignored as a WHERE clause by EF Core obviously since probably it has no idea how to parse the MethodCallExpressions.

I'm looking for a way to get *as close as possible* to the SQL query I have below with the expression tree I have.

I need to convert this:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
    .Constant<QueryTranslator`1[Setting]>(QueryTranslator`1[Setting]),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Setting,System.Boolean]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Setting,System.Boolean]>(Setting $$it)
{
    ((System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]).If (
        $$it.Value != null && .Call ($$it.Value).ContainsKey("Name")
    ) {
        ($$it.Value).Item["Name"]
    } .Else {
        null
    } > (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]).Constant<Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.LinqParameterContainer+TypedLinqParameterContainer`1[System.Int32]>(Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.LinqParameterContainer+TypedLinqParameterContainer`1[System.Int32]).TypedProperty)
    == .Constant<System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]>(True)
}
```

Into this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Setting]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([Value], 'lax $.Name') > 1; -- [Value_Name] > 1 is also fine
```

With an `ExpressionVisitor` I've succeeded in getting as close as 
WHERE [Value] = 'Something' but this only works for strings and the key name is lacking.

Comment: This is one of those cases where it will be much easier to drill down to [raw sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) instead of trying to bend the tool to your will for something that is not supported out of the box...

Comment: There's a feature on the EF Core backlog for this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4021

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Until it get "official" support, you can map the `JSON_VALUE` using the EF Core 2.0 introduced [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping).

For instance, add the following static method inside your context derived class or in separate static class as below:

```
public static class MyDbFunctions
{
    [DbFunction("JSON_VALUE", "")]
    public static string JsonValue(string source, string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

and if it is in separate class, add the following to your context `OnModelCreating` override (not needed if the method is in the context):

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyDbFunctions.JsonValue(default(string), default(string)));
```

Now you can use it inside your LINQ to Entities queries similar to `EF.Functions`. Just please note that the function returns `string`, so in order to trick the compiler to "cast" it to numeric, you can use the double cast technique shown below (tested and working in EF Core 2.1.2):

```
var query = db.Set<Setting>()
    .Where(s => (int)(object)MyDbFunctions.JsonValue(s.Value, "lax $.Name") > 1);
```

which translates to the desired

```
WHERE JSON_VALUE([Value], 'lax $.Name') > 1
```

Another (probably type safer) way to perform the conversion is to use `Convert` class methods (surprisingly supported by SqlServer EF Core provider):

```
var query = db.Set<Setting>()
    .Where(s => Convert.ToInt32(MyDbFunctions.JsonValue(s.Value, "lax $.Name")) > 1);
```

which translates to

```
WHERE CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE([Value], 'lax $.Name')) > 1
```

Comment: Hehe. Quite a hack! Deserves a couple of feet of comments in the code, I guess.

Comment: @Gert Yeah, I was surprised it actually worked :) I wanted to map `CONVERT` or `CAST`, but they don't fit in `DbFunction` definition. All that just to find (after your comment) that we can use `Convert.ToXyz` methods for that - cool :)

Comment: I will accept your answer. However I have chosen a different approach at the moment but it is situational since we work with IQueryable<T> resources. I cannot force the end user to use these functions.

Comment: Update for ef core 6. As JSON_VALUE is a built-in function we shall use fluent api with `.IsBuiltIn(true)`. The reason is that "`dbo.JSON_VALUE`" is being generated if schema name is left empty. `modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyDbFunctions.JsonValue(default(string), default(string))).HasName("JSON_VALUE").IsBuiltIn(true);`
@IvanStoev you can update your answer

Answer (score 3):

There is the breaking change in Entity Framework Core 3.X.
[DbFunction.Schema being null or empty string configures it to be in model's default schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#udf-empty-string)

And only with that example in the link I've been able to add DBFunction to our project.

Functions inside MyDbContext:

```
[DbFunction("JSON_VALUE", "dbo")]
public static string JsonValue(string source, string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();

[DbFunction("JSON_QUERY", "dbo")]
public static string JsonQuery(string source, string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

Setup:

```
modelBuilder
.HasDbFunction(typeof(MyDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(MyDbContext.JsonQuery)))
.HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create("JSON_QUERY", args, typeof(string), null));
    
modelBuilder
.HasDbFunction(typeof(MyDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(MyDbContext.JsonValue)))
.HasTranslation(args => SqlFunctionExpression.Create("JSON_VALUE", args, typeof(string), null));
```

Use (simplified):

```
var query = from sometable in _context.SomeEntity
            where MyDbContext.JsonValue(sometable.Data, "$.PrimaryKey.Id") == somevalue
            orderby sometable.Date descending
            select new SomeModel
            {
                SomeJsonArray = MyDbContext.JsonQuery(sometable.Data, "$.Changes")
            };
```

Comment: it finally worked  thank you so much