# How can a JSON_VALUE be converted to a DateTime with EF Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am mapping `JSON_VALUE` using the technique from [How to write DbFunction's translation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11295). Since not all values in the JSON are strings, conversion is sometimes necessary.

When converting to `int`, everything is fine:

```
var results = context.Set<SampleTable>()
    .Where(t1 => Convert.ToInt32(
        JsonExtensions.JsonValue(t1.SampleJson, "$.samplePath.sampleInt")) > 1);
    .ToList();
```

The resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [SampleTable] AS [t1]
WHERE (CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE([t1].[SampleJson], N'$.samplePath.sampleInt')) > 1)
```

However, when converting to `DateTime`, it doesn't work:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2019, 6, 1);
var results = context.Set<SampleTable>()
    .Where(t1 => Convert.ToDateTime(
        JsonExtensions.JsonValue(t1.SampleJson, "$.samplePath.sampleDate")) >= date);
    .ToList();
```

Instead of being mapped, `JsonValue` is called directly, which leads to the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException
>     HResult=0x80131515
>     Message=Specified method is not supported.
>     StackTrace:
>      at JsonExtensions.JsonValue(String column, String path) 
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()

Why is `DateTime` behaving differently than `int`? What can I do to make `DateTime` work correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that not all `Convert` method are supported.

In fact none of them are *standardly* supported - EF Core allows [database providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/) to add CLR method and member translators for whatever they like. For instance SqlServer provider [currently supports](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Pipeline/SqlServerConvertTranslator.cs#L15) `ToByte`, `ToDecimal`, `ToDouble`, `ToInt16`, `ToInt32`, `ToInt64` and `ToString`.

This means there is no database agnostic way of performing server side conversions.

Since you seem to be using SqlServer, as workaround I could suggest utilizing the *implicit* data conversions (currently supported by SqlServer provider) by using the "double cast" technique from my answer to a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017204/expression-tree-to-sql-with-ef-core/52018037#52018037), e.g.

```
.Where(t1 => (DateTime)(object)JsonExtensions.JsonValue(t1.SampleJson, "$.samplePath.sampleDate") >= date);
```

`(object)` cast is used to avoid the C# compiler error. During the query translation, both casts will be removed and the SQL Server implicit data conversion will eventually do the job.

Comment: Note that there is no implicit conversion. This will be a string on string comparison on SQL Server, since JSON_VALUE returns a string and EF Core will render the c# DateTime as a string. This will work very well, provided all the JSON dates are in a format compatible with [DateTime2FormatConst](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Storage/Internal/SqlServerDateTimeTypeMapping.cs).

Comment: @RichBennema I'm pretty sure `date` variable will be bound as `datetime` or `datetime2` SQL parameter, so there should be a conversion.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Here is the command that came through SQL Server Profiler: `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [SampleTable] AS [t1] WHERE (JSON_VALUE([t1].[SampleJson], N''$.samplePath.sampleDate'') >= @__date_0)',N'@__date_0 datetime2(7)',@__date_0='2019-06-01 00:00:00'`. In testing, I confirmed consistent results after updating the format of some of the dates back and forth.