# EF Core SQL Function LIKE Method with Linq Expression not working for Non String types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, ef-core-2.1

am able to create an invoke Expression with SQL Functions like as shown below

```
var likeMethod = typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("Like", new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

Expression.Call(null, likeMethod, Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), searchKeyExpression, Expression.Constant($"%{filter.Value}%"));
```

I just need to understand how can I use the functionality for columns like integer or decimal column to use with Like functions.
If I use the above expression I am getting below error. How can I use expression with ef like with non string datatype

> Argument Exeption: argument exception in Expression of System.Int32  can not be used for parameter for type System.String of method Boolean Like (Ef.DBfuntions)

#### Steps to reproduce

```cs
var likeMethod = typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("Like", new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

Expression.Call(null, likeMethod, Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), searchKeyExpression, Expression.Constant($"%{filter.Value}%"));
```

As I can see there is an option for to do it in Ef.Functions Like method in the below example

```
context.Set<MyEntity>().Where(e => EF.Functions.Like((string)(object)e.IntCol, "%1%"))
```

but how can I do this using Member Expressions.

Source :- https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9578

This is the solution for direct line query.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16195

### Further technical details

EF Core version: (ASP.NET Core 2.1)
Database Provider: (e.g. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)
Operating system: 
IDE: (e.g. Visual Studio 2017 15.4)

Comment: Imagine you were writing this directly in SQL. What **exact** SQL are you trying to generate / emulate? Are you sure that SQL actually works (i.e. did you try to run it against the database)?

Comment: It works for string , for EF Functions extension has method for two string parameters. But I want to use functionality for number types. context.Set<MyEntity>().Where(e => EF.Functions.Like((string)(object)e.IntCol, "%1%")). This converts SQL statement with like for Integer columns.this is what I found for direct function. I am looking for same with member expression

Comment: I have updated the logic for like operations with expression link. But same thing how can I use for example integer, decimal, bigint colums

Comment: It makes sense , Otherwise I won't post it here.

Comment: Isn't this all too complicated? Do you try to update multiple entities with context.Set<T>? I think you try to use EF in a way it is not meant to be used. Are you really casting an int to object then to string? That is not how C# is meant to do things

Comment: Context.set is the code from example. Point is how to do the like part with convert to string . SQL SERVER supports integer column with like

Comment: For the people who commented without understanding my question, please check Ivan Stoev answer. If you don't understand the question, you can just ignore. I posted this question because Answer is out there,  I was stuck with conversion part. Which he explained nicely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "double cast" `(string)(object)e.IntCol` is a way to trick the C# compiler to "pass" `int` argument to a method expecting `string` parameter (like `EF.Functions.Like`). Of course if the method is actually called, you'll get invalid cast exception at runtime.

But the trick works because methods like this are never "called", but translated to SQL, and SqlServer EF Core provider removes such casts and allows you to use the SqlServer implicit data conversions. I'm using the same technique (although in opposite direction) in [How can a JSON_VALUE be converted to a DateTime with EF Core 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497947/how-can-a-json-value-be-converted-to-a-datetime-with-ef-core-2-2/56515963#56515963) and [Expression tree to SQL with EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017204/expression-tree-to-sql-with-ef-core?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Here is how that maps to `Expression` methods. Given `Expression searchKeyExpression` (the concrete `Expression` type doesn't matter), the important is the `Type` returned by the `Expression.Type` property. If it is `string`, you are fine, otherwise you need to apply `(string)(object)` casts to it, which is achieved with two `Expression.Convert` calls.

Something like this:

```
Expression matchExpression = searchKeyExpression;
if (matchExpression.Type != typeof(string))
{
    matchExpression = Expression.Convert(matchExpression, typeof(object));
    matchExpression = Expression.Convert(matchExpression, typeof(string));
}
var pattern = Expression.Constant($"%{filter.Value}%");
var callLike = Expression.Call(
    typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions), "Like", Type.EmptyTypes,
    Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), matchExpression, pattern);
```

Comment: That was brilliant trick. Happy that I am not the only faced this situation. Actually Ity almost my sleeping time. Will check and let you know as mark as answer. I was stuck at the conversion part. But one question u mentioned Type.EmptyTypes I didn't get that part

Comment: This is a handy overload of `Expression.Call` for "calling" static methods. The 3rd argument is `Type[]` representing the generic type arguments of the method. For non generic methods we simply pass empty type array, what exactly the `Type.EmptyTypes` is :) Of course your way (using another `Call` overload) also works when you pass the correct arguments.

Comment: We were using the same fix in EF Core 2.2, but it now no longer works in EF Core 3.*.
The exception message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Stacktrace: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionExtensions.InferTypeMapping(SqlExpression[] expressions) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionFactory.ApplyTypeMappingOnLike(LikeExpression likeExpression) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionFactory.ApplyTypeMapping(SqlExpression sqlExpression, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping)

Comment: Updating Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore  and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer to 3.1.0 fixes this issue